# Running sum with max and min cap in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
|ID1| ID2| Date       |count |
+---+----+------------+------+
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-24 | 3    | 
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-25 | 3    |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-26 | 3    |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-27 | 1    |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-28 | -3   |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-24 | 1    |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-25 | -3   |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-26 | 3    |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-27 | 3    |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-28 | 3    |
```

I am interested in calculating the running sum with a min cap of 0 and a max cap of 8. Resulting table would look like this.

```
|ID1| ID2| Date       |count |runningSum|
+---+----+------------+------+----------+
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-24 | 3    | 3        |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-25 | 3    | 6        |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-26 | 3    | 8        |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-27 | 1    | 8        |
|1  | 1  | 2019-07-28 | -3   | 5        |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-24 | 1    | 1        |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-25 | -3   | 0        |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-26 | 3    | 3        |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-27 | 3    | 6        |
|1  | 2  | 2019-07-28 | 3    | 8        |
```

I know that Oracle has many different solution to address this problem, like 
described here in number 7 
https://blog.jooq.org/2016/04/25/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/. Does anything as simple as this exist for Microsoft SQL Server.

Note that I am **not** allowed to create tables, temporary tables or table variables.

**EDIT** I am using Azure Datawarehouse where recursive CTE and cursor statements are not available. Are there really not any other ways to solve this problem in SQL Server?

Comment: What's your logic in the `runningSum`?  It doesn't seem to line up with the `count`.

Comment: He sums the values until the max value of 8...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  2012 and up or something prior to 2012?

Comment: I'm using version 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with window functions, alas.  The problem is that the caps introduce a state change, so you have to process the rows incrementally to get the value for a given row.

A recursive CTE does iteration, so it can do what you want:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id1, id2 order by date) as seqnum
      from <yourtable> t
     ),
     cte as (
      select id1, id2, date, count,
             (case when count < 0 then 0
                   when count > 8 then 8
                   else count
              end) as runningsum,
             seqnum
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.id1, cte.id2, t.date, t.count,
             (case when t.count + cte.runningsum < 0 then 0
                   when t.count + cte.runningsum > 8 then 8
                   else t.count + cte.runningsum
              end) as runningsum, t.seqnum
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1 and
              t.id1 = cte.id1 and t.id2 = cte.id2
     )
select *
from cte
order by id1, id2, date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=551e035054f016780d4b2a59392db505) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that very similar code will work in Oracle 12C, which supports recursive CTEs.  In earlier versions of Oracle, you can use `connect by`.

Comment: This is a correct result for SQL server, therefore I am gonna accept your answer. However I am still interested in a way to solve this for SQL Azure Datawarehouse